# Angular-6 show and hide drop-down select option not showing proper data

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6, dropdown

I have 2 types of `drop-down` based on the select **value column** `drop-down` will show.

(**one for to show database data**, **another one for to show desktop data**.)

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-3n238j?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

**app.componet.html**

```
<!-- show database data -->
<select *ngIf="isdbShow" [(ngModel)]="dynamicArray[i].title2" class="form-control">
    <option *ngFor="let data of dynamicArray[i].dropdownData;">{{data}}</option>
</select>

<!-- show desktop data -->
<select *ngIf="isdesktopShow" [(ngModel)]="dynamicArray[i].title2" class="form-control">
    <option *ngFor="let data of dynamicArray[i].dropdownData;">{{data.name}}</option>
</select>
```

**My issue is below**

1. In 1st row if I select `desktop` it will show desktop data's in **value column** `drop-down`.
2. In 2nd row if I select `database`, `desktop` will be showed as `[object object]` check bellow image

[image]

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, VERSION, OnInit } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  dynamicArray: Array<any> = [];
  newDynamic: any = {};
  dbValue = ["mysql", "oracle", "mongo"];
  desktopValue = [{'id':'1', 'name':'dell'}, {'id':'2', 'name':'lenovo'}, {'id':'3', 'name':'hp'}];
  isdbShow:boolean = false;
  isdesktopShow:boolean = false;
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.newDynamic = { title1: "", title2: "", dropdownData: [] };
    this.dynamicArray.push(this.newDynamic);
  }
  addRow(index) {
    this.newDynamic = { title1: "", title2: "", dropdownData: [] };
    this.dynamicArray.push(this.newDynamic);
    console.log(this.dynamicArray);
    return true;
  }

  deleteRow(index) {
    if (this.dynamicArray.length == 1) {
      return false;
    } else {
      this.dynamicArray.splice(index, 1);
      return true;
    }
  }

  changed(value, index) {
    let dropdownData;
    if (value == 1) {
      this.isdbShow = true;
      this.isdesktopShow = false;
      this.dynamicArray[index].dropdownData = this.dbValue;
    }

    if (value == 2) {
      this.isdbShow = false;
      this.isdesktopShow = true;
      this.dynamicArray[index].dropdownData = this.desktopValue;
    }
  }
}
```

> Please check the flow in my demo link with same scenario.
> 1st row select `desktop` and 2nd row `database`

Comment: You display `dynamicArray` in both `select` options, but you change the type of data in this array in the `changed` method. One copntains string and the other contains objects. Why do you need to change de `dynamicArray` instead of having two different arrays, one for each `select`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<select *ngIf="isdbShow" [(ngModel)]="dynamicArray[i].title2" class="form-control">
                <option *ngFor="let data of dynamicArray[i].dropdownData;">{{data?.name ? data?.name : data}}</option>
              </select>
```